# Function that will select value from SQL table and do a sum based on another column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a query to sum up the `hours` in a table. Which hours need to be selected depends on the `Start Date` column. If the start date is in the past, then it should take `Remaining Hours`, if it's in the future it should take `Budgeted Hours`.

| Start Date | Budgeted Hours | Remaining Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 1, 2022 | 15 | 3 |
| Feb 1, 2022 | 12 | 0 |
| Mar 1, 2022 | 14 | 6 |
| Apr 1, 2022 | 15 | 13 |

In the example above the summed up hours should be 24 (3 + 0 + 6 + 15).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a function for this, just a `CASE` expression:

```
DECLARE @now datetime = GETDATE();

SELECT SUM
(
  CASE WHEN [Start Date] < @now 
  THEN [Remaining Hours]
  ELSE [Budgeted Hours] 
  END
)
FROM dbo.tablename;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the function `case`

> ```
> create table ops(
> startDate date,
> Budgeted int,
> Remaining int);
> ```

> ```
> insert into ops values
> ('2022-01-01',15,3),
> ('2022-02-01',12,0),
> ('2022-03-01',14,6),
> ('2022-04-01',15,13),
> ('2022-05-01',10,18);
> ```

> ```
> select
>   startDate,
>   Budgeted,
>   Remaining,
>   case when startDate < getDate()
>     then Remaining
>   else Budgeted
>   end Hours
> from ops;
> ```

> ```
> startDate  | Budgeted | Remaining | Hours
> :--------- | -------: | --------: | ----:
> 2022-01-01 |       15 |         3 |     3
> 2022-02-01 |       12 |         0 |     0
> 2022-03-01 |       14 |         6 |     6
> 2022-04-01 |       15 |        13 |    15
> 2022-05-01 |       10 |        18 |    10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=ad0091894948bfc7f6efcf8b33cca9c7)*